# Unable to store sessions in Redis

Tags: php, redis

So, I have `XAMPP` with `PHP 5.5.24` and I have `Redis` installed. I can `set` and `get` variables from `Redis` like:

```
$redis = new Redis();
$redis->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379);
$redis->set("var","val"); // it is working ok
```

What I want now is to store sessions in Redis. So, I configured `session.save_handler` and `session.save_path` in my `php.ini` like so:

```
session.save_handler = redis
session.save_path = "tcp://localhost:6379?weight=1"
```

But it is not working. I just get these errors:

```
Warning: session_start(): in C:\....

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RedisException' with message 'Connection  closed'
```

I tried this:

```
session.save_path = "tcp://localhost:6379/"
```

and this:

```
session.save_path = "localhost:6379"
```

But still see the same errors.

**EDIT**

By the way, I installed Redis from [here](https://github.com/msopentech/redis)

Comment: I have the same problem, I am using Debian Jessie (php 5.6 and redis 3.0.1).

Comment: I finally made it work with the help of this library https://github.com/nrk/predis